# Chromedriver for chrome version 65

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am working on py script with selenium for taking screenshot of web page from Chrome browser version 65. I cant find compatible Chromedriver for this chrome version 65 in official website.

I used chromedriver version for 71 (oldest available chromedriver)and it threw this error

```
  File "selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402)
```

Where can i download driver for chrome version 65. Or any other option to fix this error. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could try ChromeDriver 2.36, but it is outdated, and may not work. => https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36/. According to the notes, the ChromeDriver `Supports Chrome v63-65`.